# xsl create two tables by join counter field

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document:

```
<Cable>A030.000  </Cable>
<Address>
<ZIP>11411</ZIP>
<City>A-City</City>
<Street>B-Street</Steet>
<Hause>8</Hause>
<CableData>
<Damping>0242</Damping>
<DM-1>400</DM-1>
<Length-1>0054</Length-1>
<DM-2>400</DM-2>
<Length-2>0041</Length-2>
<DM-3>400</DM-3>
<Length-3>0024</Length-3>
</CableData>
</Address>
<Address>
<ZIP>11511</ZIP>
<City>A-City</City>
<Street>B-Street</Steet>
<Hause>10</Hause>
<CableData>
<Damping>0242</Damping>
<DM-1>400</DM-1>
<Length-1>0054</Length-1>
</CableData>
</Address>
```

Here every Address node has a child node CableData which in turn has Damping and up to 5 pairs DM-xx Length-xx.

What I want to achieve is to create with XSL 2 tables joined by a common field row counter. The first table should contain Address info except for CableData, whereas the other one should display CableData content for each Address. A common data for the tables is in the first column, i e row number, and that is to be used to join data in both tables.

1-st Table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Num</th>
<th>Zip</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>City dstr</th>
<th>Street</th>
<th>Hause</th>
<th>Hause Ltr</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>12345</td>
  <td>A-City</td>
  <td>North</td>
  <td>B-Street</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>12345</td>
  <td>A-City</td>
  <td>North</td>
  <td>B-Street</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>D</td>
 </tr>  
 </table>
```

2-nd table

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Num</th>
  <th>Damping</th>
  <th>DM-1</th>
<th>Length-1</th>
<th>DM-2</th>
<th>Length-2</th>
<th>DM-3</th>
<th>Length-3</th>
<th>DM-4</th>
<th>Length-4</th>
<th>DM-5</th>
<th>Length-5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>0242</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>0054</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>0041</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>0024</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>0242</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>0054</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

The common column in both tables is the Num.

Comment: Please (a) post a **well-formed** example of the XML input and (b) explain where exactly are you having a difficulty with this.

Comment: @uL1 Please do not edit OP's code: you don't know what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT 1:** Please provide complete and well-formed documents like Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example like @michael.hor257k mentioned already in comments.

**HINT 2:** Please verify your given xml. These are not valid. [for example: `<street>` is closed by `</steet>`]

**HINT 3:** Tell us, where the problem is. If you just search for someone, who does your work, this is the wrong place to ask. Keep this in mind.

**Have a look at:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="createAddressesTab"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="createDampingTab"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="createAddressesTab">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>City dstr</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Hause</th>
                <th>Hause Ltr</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Address">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ZIP"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="City"/></td>
                    <td><!-- provide some xml for this tag --></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Street"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Hause"/></td>
                    <td><!-- provide some xml for this tag --></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="createDampingTab">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>Damping</th>
                <th>DM-1</th>
                <th>Length-1</th>
                <th>DM-2</th>
                <th>Length-2</th>
                <th>DM-3</th>
                <th>Length-3</th>
                <th>DM-4</th>
                <th>Length-4</th>
                <th>DM-5</th>
                <th>Length-5</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Address">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Damping"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/DM-1"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Length-1"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/DM-2"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Length-2"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/DM-3"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Length-3"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/DM-4"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Length-4"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/DM-5"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="CableData/Length-5"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation:**
Pretty straight forward for a "advanced" one. It is fully functional in XSLT 1.0. Calling 2 named templates who does the requested work.

It does the work. Please ask via comment, if there is any problem. *If you like, please give a up and/or close this question*